# how to change the color of an svg image in xml file(in geoserver)?is it possible to change in geoserver?

Tags: xml, svg, geoserver

this is my code.i want to change color of svg image here itself. even though I change the color code it is not working.i am getting the black and white color. what is the error in my code?

```
<se:PointSymbolizer>
<se:Graphic>
<!--Parametric SVG-->
<se:ExternalGraphic>
<se:OnlineResource xlink:href="ForServer/DRY.svg?fill=%23e01987&amp;fill-opacity=1&amp;outline=%23e01987&amp;outline-opacity=1&amp;outline-width=0" xlink:type="simple"/>
<se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
</se:ExternalGraphic>
<!--Plain SVG fallback, no parameters-->
<se:ExternalGraphic>
<se:OnlineResource xlink:href="ForServer/DRY.svg" xlink:type="simple"/>
<se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
</se:ExternalGraphic>
<!--Well known marker fallback-->
<se:Mark>
<se:WellKnownName>square</se:WellKnownName>
<se:Fill>
<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e01987</se:SvgParameter>
</se:Fill>
<se:Stroke>
<se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e01987</se:SvgParameter>
<se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
</se:Stroke>
</se:Mark>
<se:Size>11</se:Size>
</se:Graphic>
</se:PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: You might get a better response from [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoserver).

Comment: Maybe you can do this using composition: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/example.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor
  version="1.0.0"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
    http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd
">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>redflag</Name>
        <UserStyle>
        <Name>burg</Name>
        <Title>A small red flag</Title>
        <Abstract>A sample of how to use an SVG based symbolizer
        </Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
       <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="burg02.svg" />
                    <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
                <Size>
                 <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
                </Size>
            </Graphic>
         </PointSymbolizer>
        <PolygonSymbolizer>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#1eff00</CssParameter> <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
          <Stroke>
            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter> <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
          </Stroke>
        </PolygonSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using [composition](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/example.html). I made a svg picture with only black colors to use as an alpha mask. Then I made a square Mark bigger than the picture just to apply the color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
  <NamedLayer>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="YOUR_SVG_FILE.svg"/>
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>45</Size>
            </Graphic>
            <VendorOption name="composite-base">true</VendorOption>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#1e9e1e</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>50</Size>
            </Graphic>
            <VendorOption name="composite">source-in</VendorOption>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

See also https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer doesn't (AFAIK) support the colouring of SVG symbols via the SLD file, it will always be the colours that are set in the SVG.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the reply

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving an image as .svg, I have converted SVG to png and gave .png image, It perfectly works!!!